# Imageless Background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have being wondering thinking what do one achieve this type of background in css for quite a while now. It's an image background, yet the image does not seem to be there. You cant download the image and cant drag it along. Please see the Pink stylish image background  [here](https://www.etsy.com/) . How can I achieve that? Or can some one help me with the feature name? Or perhaps a good link where I can learn or see the example on that? I just try googling but don't know what it's call. Another example is the chinese new year background [Here](http://www.stjobs.sg/).

Comment: Those are just standard CSS background images. `background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image):
New year:

```
.homepage-background-cny {
    background: url("../../img/cny.jpg") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
}
```

Etsy:

```
#seasonal-hero {
    background: url("//img0.etsystatic.com/site-assets/homepage-carousel/valentine-gift-hero-v3.jpg") repeat scroll center center #FEEEEF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    min-width: 1030px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Background images usually cannot be dragged, the source of the elements background can be found with the inspector:
[image]

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1v1u8j1o/)

```css
div{
    height:300px;
    background: url('http://lorempizza.com/1000/500');
}
```

```html
<div>Background-Image</div>
```

Comment: Thank you man. I think thats what i am looking for. Will study it.

Answer (score 1):

They're just CSS background images:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wt9t4pp0/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    This is the content.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(//img0.etsystatic.com/site-assets/homepage-carousel/valentine-gift-hero-v3.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you use the background-image rule:

background-image: url("//img0.etsystatic.com/site-assets/homepage-carousel/valentine-gift-hero-v3.jpg");

this is the one on the page you link uses.

Best,
Michael